# PyCharm : Change documention window's font

Tags: pycharm

[image: Documentation Tool]

How to change the font family (not font size) of the Documentation window in PyCharm?

Comment: Good question. I'd like to know as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the size of the font (click on the gear icon). There is no way to change the font itself, but there is [a feature request you can vote for](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100877).